# initializer element is not constant - for static initialisation

Tags: c

### Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
        static int a = 1;
        static int b = a;
        printf("\n a : %d b : %d \n",a,b);
        return 0;
}
```

### o/p:

```
static.c: In function ‘main’:
static.c:4:2: error: initializer element is not constant
```

I see the static variables compile properly when we initialise it with constants or left un-intialised. But as like other stack variables the static variables which resides in the data segment also gets allocated at the compile time and get the virtual addresses on the disk. The heap variables gets the physical address at run time and intialises the variables at the run time. 
Why is the static variable can't be initialised with a variable.

Comment: Is it only becoz of the rules of the language. \

Answer (score 2):

N1570 §6.7.9/p4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

Comment: stack has thread storage duration but that can be intialised with other stack varibales too

Comment: @Angus I don't think you understand what "thread storage duration" means.

Comment: Is thread storage duration and stack storage duration are two different things. I went through the definition of the thread duration. It appears to be same as the stack duration. Please explain the difference between both.

Comment: stack and thread has same storage duration . It dies when the thread or stack ends

Comment: @Angus: There is no thing such as "stack storage duration", at least not in C. Standard doesn't even mention nor define term "stack".

Comment: Does the auto variables that are allocated inside a function and the thread has the same storage duration

Answer (score 2):

In C, static variables can only be initialized using constant literals.

```
int main() 
{
int c=10
static int i = c; //error
printf(" value of i = %d", i);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

All variable with static  must be initialized before execution of main() starts. So a value which `is not known at translation time cannot` be used for `initialization of static` variables.

Comment: constant expressions